# I want to transform this code to work wit full sentences

Tags: python, excel, pandas, nlp

Iam trying to check if keyword occurs in the  sentence and then  add  the said keyword. I managed to write this solution but it only works if the search term is one word (said keyword). How to improve  it to work when keyword occurs in a sentence? Here is my code:

```
keyword = []
for i in keywords['keyword']:
    keyword.append(i) #this was in a dataframe after readin xlsx file with Pandas so I made it a list

hit = []
for i in phrase['Search term']:
    if i in keyword:
        hit.append(i)
    else:
        hit.append("blank")

phrase['Keyword'] = hit
```

This only works when a single keyword occurs in "Phrase" - like "cat" but won't work if the word "cat" is part of a sentence. Any pointers to improve it ?
Thank you all in advance

Comment: Hard to tell what you are trying to do and where the problem might be if you don't include a minimal example of `keyword` and `phrase['Search term']` with items that should and shouldn't match. ... [mcve]

Comment: Keyword is a list of single words like :
1 cat
2 Dog
3 Human
Search term is a list of sentences that may contain some keywords, example:
1 Dog crossed the road
2 nothing happened
3 Cat ate a bird

I want to cross check if the sentences contain  any keyword and add that keyword in the column next to a sentence. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here.** However, I'm going to point an issue that might help you.

In your comment you said that `keyword` is a list of words and `phrase['Search term']` is a list of sentences.

```
for i in phrase['Search term']:
    if i in keyword:
        hit.append(i)
    ...
```

In this part of your code you are checking if a **entire sentence** `i` can be found **in** any of the **single words** in `keyword`. That logic is flawed, you need to check if a word exists in the sentence, not the other way around.

Something like this:

```
for i in phrase['Search term']:
    for j in keyword:
        if j in i:
            hit.append(i)
        ...
```

**This is an example** you will need to adjust to your purpose, since now it will check word for word.

The code above may lead to undesirable behavior since it checks if a smaller string(word) exists inside a larger string(sentence). It doesn't really check for words. For example, if looking for **cat** in a sentence like:

> this patient is **cat**atonic

Will trigger your if statement as `True`. A way to minimize this is spliting your sentence in a list of words and checking if the word is found inside the list. Like this:

```
for i in phrase['Search term']:
    for j in keyword:
        if j in i.split(" "):
            hit.append(i)
        ...
```